# MySQL Query to join three table and get data from 2nd and 3rd table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I HAVE 3 TABLES :

Table1: Table Name: FULL_DATA

```
DATE        ORDER_NO               AMOUNT   MODE
01-04-2019  ADVANVCE.:ORD1971718    5000    DEBIT-CARD
01-04-2019  ADVANVCE.:ORD1961718    6000    CASH
01-04-2019  ADVANVCE.:ORD2001819    8000    CASH
02-04-2019  ADVANVCE.:ORD2011819    10000   CASH
02-04-2019  ADVANVCE.:ORD0891819    3000    CASH
02-04-2019  ADVANVCE.:ORD2021819    8000    DEBIT-CARD
02-04-2019  ADVANVCE.:ORD2031819    12000   CASH
03-04-2019  ADVANVCE.:ORD2041819    14000   CASH
03-04-2019  ADVANVCE.:ORD2051819 17000  CASH
03-04-2019  ADVANVCE.:ORD2061819    14000   CASH
03-04-2019  ADVANVCE.:ORD2061819    15000   DEBIT-CARD
03-04-2019  ADVANVCE.:ORD2071819    4000    DEBIT-CARD
03-04-2019  ADVANVCE.:ORD2071819    1000    CASH
04-04-2019  ADVANVCE.:ORD2101819    500 CASH
04-04-2019  ADVANVCE.:ORD2091819    1000    CASH
04-04-2019  ADVANVCE.:ORD2081819    2000    CASH
04-04-2019  ADVANVCE.:ORD0471819    8000    CASH
```

Table2: Table Name: ORDER_DETAILS

```
ORDER_NO    ITEM_NAME   CUSTOMER_ID
ORD2001819  ITEM-1      7
ORD2011819  ITEM-2      6
ORD2021819  ITEM-3      5
ORD2021819  ITEM-4      5
ORD2021819  ITEM-5      5
ORD2021819  ITEM-6      5
ORD2031819  ITEM-7      8
ORD2041819  ITEM-8      67
ORD2041819  ITEM-9      67
ORD2051819  ITEM-10     89
ORD2061819  ITEM-11     54
ORD2061819  ITEM-12     54
ORD2071819  ITEM-13     11
ORD2101819  ITEM-14     12
ORD2091819  ITEM-15     14
ORD2081819  ITEM-16     16
ORD1971718  ITEM-17     68
ORD1971718  ITEM-18     68
ORD0471819  ITEM-19     90
ORD0891819  ITEM-20     44
ORD1961718  ITEM-21     55
```

Table3: Table Name: CUSTOMER_DETAILS

```
CUSTOMER_ID    CUSTOMER_NAME
7              CUSTOMER-1
6              CUSTOMER-24
5              CUSTOMER-39
8              CUSTOMER-40
67             CUSTOMER-15
89             CUSTOMER-66
54             CUSTOMER-7
11             CUSTOMER-89
12             CUSTOMER-9
14             CUSTOMER-10
16             CUSTOMER-11
68             CUSTOMER-121
90             CUSTOMER-134
44             CUSTOMER-147
55             CUSTOMER-158
```

QUERY TO `JOIN` THESE TABLE WHICH WILL TAKE DATE, ORDER_NO, AMOUNT, MODE COLUMNS FROM FULL_DATA TABLE AND `JOIN` ITS ORDER_NO (GET ORDER NO BY SPLITTING ORDER NO BY ":") WITH ORDER_DETAILS TABLE AND GET IT CUSTOMER ID AND THEN `JOIN` ITS CUSTOMER ID WITH CUSTOMER DETAILS TABLE AND GET CUSTOMER NAMES????

THE DATA WILL BE LOOK LIKE THESE:

Final Query Result:

```
DATE        CUSTOMER_NAME   ORDER_NO               AMOUNT   MODE
01-04-2019  CUSTOMER-121    ADVANVCE.:ORD1971718    5000    DEBIT-CARD
01-04-2019  CUSTOMER-158    ADVANVCE.:ORD1961718    6000    CASH
01-04-2019  CUSTOMER-1      ADVANVCE.:ORD2001819    8000    CASH
02-04-2019  CUSTOMER-24     ADVANVCE.:ORD2011819    10000   CASH
02-04-2019  CUSTOMER-147    ADVANVCE.:ORD0891819    3000    CASH
02-04-2019  CUSTOMER-39     ADVANVCE.:ORD2021819    8000    DEBIT-CARD
02-04-2019  CUSTOMER-40     ADVANVCE.:ORD2031819    12000   CASH
03-04-2019  CUSTOMER-15     ADVANVCE.:ORD2041819    14000   CASH
03-04-2019  CUSTOMER-66     ADVANVCE.:ORD2051819    17000   CASH
03-04-2019  CUSTOMER-7      ADVANVCE.:ORD2061819    14000   CASH
03-04-2019  CUSTOMER-7      ADVANVCE.:ORD2061819    15000   DEBIT-CARD
03-04-2019  CUSTOMER-89     ADVANVCE.:ORD2071819    4000    DEBIT-CARD
03-04-2019  CUSTOMER-89     ADVANVCE.:ORD2071819    1000    CASH
04-04-2019  CUSTOMER-9      ADVANVCE.:ORD2101819    500     CASH
04-04-2019  CUSTOMER-10     ADVANVCE.:ORD2091819    1000    CASH
04-04-2019  CUSTOMER-11     ADVANVCE.:ORD2081819    2000    CASH
04-04-2019  CUSTOMER-134    ADVANVCE.:ORD0471819    8000    CASH
```

Comment: Don't write using all caps, it's very hard to read. And clarify your question, four question marks doesn't make the question more obvious.

Comment: Sorry i just stuck in this question for 4 days..

Comment: To me it looks like a simple join so you really need to clarify the question and what you've been stuck with for 4 days.

Comment: I will remember it next time..

Comment: If i simply left join my table full_data and order_details it showing same record many times accirding to order_details table like ORD2021819 if i simply left join it will show me this order 4 times

Comment: Hi Sujoy, Share the code you have tried

Comment: @SujoyDebnath can you explain why the 1st row of your "Final Query Result" has amount=5000?

Comment: Select FULL_DATA.DATE, CUSTOMER_DETAILS.CUSTOMER_NAME, FULL_DATA.ORDER_NO, FULL_DATA.AMOUNT, FULL_DATA.MODE FROM MYDB.FULL_DATA LEFT JOIN MYDB.ORDER_DETAILS ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(FULL_DATA.ORDER_NO,':',-1)=ORDER_DETAILS.ORDER_NO LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER_DETAILS ON ORDER_DETAILS.CUSTOMER_ID=CUSTOMER_DETAILS.CUSTOMER_ID WHERE FULL_DATA.DATE BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2019-04-04'  ORDER BY FULL_DATA.DATE ASC

Comment: Sorry forpas its my mistake i have edited my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a join by selecting distinct values for customer_id and order_no from order_detaisl

```
SELECT f.DATE, CUSTOMER_NAME, f.ORDER_NO, AMOUNT, MODE 
FROM FULL_DATA f
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT customer_id, order_no 
      FROM ORDER_DETAILS) o ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(f.ORDER_NO,':',-1)= o.ORDER_NO 
JOIN CUSTOMER_DETAILS c ON o.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID 
WHERE f.DATE BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2019-04-04' 
ORDER BY f.DATE ASC
```

Comment: I think this code is perferct for my software....thank you very much....

Answer (score 1):

If those order numbers in the data are always the last part after the `:`?

```
SELECT
 d.DATE, 
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.CUSTOMER_NAME) AS CUSTOMER_NAMES,
 d.ORDER_NO,
 d.AMOUNT,
 d.MODE
FROM FULL_DATA d
LEFT JOIN ORDER_DETAILS o 
  ON o.ORDER_NO = RTRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(d.ORDER_NO,':',-1))
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER_DETAILS c ON c.CUSTOMER_ID = o.CUSTOMER_ID
GROUP BY 
 d.DATE, 
 d.ORDER_NO,
 d.AMOUNT,
 d.MODE
```

There are multiple items per order.
In theory there could be more than 1 customer per order.
 So a GROUP_CONCAT is used here instead of a MAX.

Comment: In my opinion it should be something like `SUBSTR(FULL_DATA.ORDER_NO, LOCATE(':', FULL_DATA.ORDER_NO) + 1)` but really slower than @LukStorms suggestion.

Comment: I already find the way to get order no from the text my problem is i cant join these tables in proper way

Comment: Do you need to sum the AMOUNT field values? You have 5000 in your first row for order ORD1971718. It seems to be strange result

Comment: No i just need customer name in full_data table

Comment: Select FULL_DATA.DATE, CUSTOMER_DETAILS.CUSTOMER_NAME, FULL_DATA.ORDER_NO, FULL_DATA.AMOUNT, FULL_DATA.MODE FROM MYDB.FULL_DATA LEFT JOIN MYDB.ORDER_DETAILS ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(FULL_DATA.ORDER_NO,':',-1)=ORDER_DETAILS.ORDER_NO LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER_DETAILS ON ORDER_DETAILS.CUSTOMER_ID=CUSTOMER_DETAILS.CUSTOMER_ID WHERE FULL_DATA.DATE BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2019-04-04'  ORDER BY FULL_DATA.DATE ASC

Comment: I have tried this code this code shwing customer names but showing data manytimes

Answer (score 0):

It will take every order no from full_data table and find order no customer details using 2nd and 3rd table and show me customer name after date column